# Вопрос по ссылкам в с++

Tags: c++, c++11, ссылки

Я нашла книгу  где  написано что при создании ссылки ее нужно инициализировать и что после  этого  ей нельзя присвоить  другое  значения. Но я всегда  присваивала  другое  значения:

```
int main()
 {
  int a = 10;
  int& b = a;
  b= 18;
  std::cout<<a;
  std:;cout<< b;
 
  int c= 90;
  b = c;
  std::cout<<a;
  std::cout<< b;
  std::cout<< c;

  return 0;
 }
```

Что я не так понимаю?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Смотрите - ссылка - это псевдоним другой переменной.

Вы **НЕ МОЖЕТЕ** сделать ее псевдонимом некоторой иной переменной, кроме как только той, которая указана при инициализации. Т.е. вы не можете изменить ее именно как ссылку. В этом смысле вы не можете "присвоить" (я бы предпочел - "назначить") ей другую переменную.

Вы **МОЖЕТЕ** присваивать ей другое *значение*, но это будет присвоением нового значения переменной, на которую она ссылается.

Так понятнее? Просто на русском языке высказать это кратко, одним словом - не получается.

Comment: я поняла теперь а,b,c = 90.

Comment: Да, потому что фактически после `b = c` переменная `b` *продолжает ссылаться на `a`*, так что меняется *значение* переменной `a`.

Comment: Такой вопрос. а для указателей  ж это  не работает7 там  ж можна  присваивать  другое  значения указателю?

Comment: Да, но обратите внимание - для указателя есть `p = &x` - присваивание указателя, и `*p = x` - присваивание значения по указываемому  адресу. Они синтаксически разные, в то время как для ссылки использована разность конструкций инициализации и присваивания.

Comment: p = &x -  так уже  ж нельзя  когда я сделала  перед этим int* p = &a; а так  можно *p = x;

Comment: Да можно по всякому, в зависимости от того, что есть что и какого типа :) И что вы хотите. После `p = &x;` указатель `p` перестанет указывать на `a`, и станет указывать на `x`, так что `*p = 5;` присвоит значение 5 уже не переменной `a`, а переменной `x`.